# Send by email in customer invoice accounting module not working odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Hello everyone in the accounting module I have created a customer invoice And validated it when I tried to send it by email it seems everything works fine but I am not receiving any message in my email. but when I create a quotation in the sales module and send it by email everything works fine and I am receiving a message in email. Outgoing Email server working fine. Do I need to edit some Things?

Comment: Have you checked on Messages under technical menu?